# jQuery Accordion Menu Expansion and Optimization

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am new to programming with jQuery and am having trouble with a custom jQuery accordion. My attempts at expanding the accordion for the current link have been unsuccessful and I am at a loss as to how to get it working.

**Main question:** How can I get Section [2] to work (expanding and highlighting the currently active links)?

I believe this problem has to do with how I am going about selecting the elements. The three lines of code I have in that section is currently my best shot. It highlights and expands *all* of the links and highlights *all* of the accordion headers (h2). This is of course not what I'm going for at all. My numerous online searches have been fruitless as the accordions seem to either be structured differently or I am severely misunderstanding some key concepts since none of the answers seem to fit in this case.

**Secondary question:** How can I optimize Section 3? The code itself is simple but I repeated it several times and ended up with the confusing mess in section [3] below.

**Here is my current jQuery code**, [adapted from this tutorial](http://jordanrodriguez.com/jquery-nested-accordion-menu#nested-accordion-demo):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

// [1] initialize
var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div'),
    childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').siblings('div'),
    lowDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h4').siblings('div'),
    img1 = '...',
    img2 = '...';

// [2] expand current link
$('#nestedAccordion a').addClass("a-active");
$('#nestedAccordion a').parents('div').slideDown();
$('#nestedAccordion a').parents('div').find('h2').addClass("open");

// [3] accordion movement (repetitious...)
$('#nestedAccordion h2').click(function () {
    parentDivs.slideUp();
    $('#nestedAccordion h2').removeClass("open");
        $('#nestedAccordion h3').removeClass("open");
        $('#nestedAccordion h4').removeClass("open");
    $('#nestedAccordion h2').find('img').attr('src', img2);
    $('#nestedAccordion h3').find('img').attr('src', img2);
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img1);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img2);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
});
$('#nestedAccordion h3').click(function () {
    childDivs.slideUp();
    $('#nestedAccordion h3').removeClass("open");
        $('#nestedAccordion h4').removeClass("open");
    $('#nestedAccordion h3').find('img').attr('src', img2);
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img1);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img2);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
});
$('#nestedAccordion h4').click(function () {
    lowDivs.slideUp();
    $('#nestedAccordion h4').removeClass("open");
    $('#nestedAccordion h4').find('img').attr('src', img2);
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img1);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', img2);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

});

And here is the **Accordion HTML structure**. Each level has a div so that the jQuery slideUp and slideDown functions will work - the div expands and collapses.

```
<div id="nestedAccordion">
<h2>Top-level Heading</h2>
    <div>
    <h3>Mid-level Heading</h3>
        <div>
        <h4>Bottom-level Heading</h4>
            <div>
            <ol>
                <li>Link</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making your own accordion, I would recommend something more along the lines of

```
$(function() {
  $(".accordion-title").click(function(){
    body = $(this).closest("accordion").find(".accordion-body")
    if (body.is(".closed")){
      body.removeClass("closed")
    }else{
      body.addClass("closed")
    }
  })
});
```

Then your html would look something like

```
<div class="accordion">
   <div class="accordion-title"></div>
   <div class="accordion-body"></div>
</div>
```

And for css

```
.closed {
    display: none;
}
```

In this way you do not need to repeat the code for each accordion individually.
And the show and hide functions allow for somewhat simpler html structures.

Also I would recommend using the $ in place of jQuery as it is more readable (personal opinion).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried a jsfiddle with the code you provided but can't seem to get it to work. Good point about using '$' instead of 'jQuery' - I edited it in my post. Here is my jsfiddle attempt: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Turgon/JFm35/2)

Comment: @Turgon I updated your jsfiddle a bit.  Jsfiddle automatically loads your javascript for you so you don't need the '$(document).ready' surrounding it.

Comment: Ah I was wondering about whether that was necessary, thanks. How do I view the updated jsfiddle? I tried editing the end of the url to /3/ , 4, 5, etc. but it only came up with '404 not found.' I posted my newest update on /6/ with information from your updated post above. Sublevels don't seem to be working the way I expected? Thank you very much for the help - I appreciate it!

Comment: @Turgon I think this is what you mean by [sub-levels](http://jsfiddle.net/JFm35/7/) but let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: No, [here is what I mean by sublevels](http://jsfiddle.net/Turgon/JFm35/8/ "jsfiddle") (I got them working now). Now in this setup how do you go about selecting all of the .accordions except for 'body?' The goal being to only have one .accordion open at a time. Similarly I need a way to target the .accordions with css  based on their level (top-level, mid-level, etc.) and the only way I can think to do this is by reverting to my original setup.

Comment: @Turgon Sorry looks like I had pasted you the wrong fiddle.  Anyway, you could add something like $(".accordion-body").addClass("closed") at the start of the javascript function (in order to close all of the accordions).  Then you could have the line following body be something like body.parents(".closed").removeClass("closed") (in order to ensure the active accordion isn't hidden by one of its parents). This allows you to remove the if as well since it would now always be opening the accordion.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48MP2/1/).